# How do you use SetEnv to read variables in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, setenv, env

I want to set an env variable that has the DOC_ROOT info but nothing

```
SetEnv PROJECT_BASE %{ENV:DOC_ROOT}
SetEnv LAYOUT_HOME  %{ENV:PROJECT_BASE}"/html/app/wordpress/"
```

and then be able to access LAYOUT_HOME in php

How can I do this? The above is not working for me...

The problem is the base path is different on diff environments =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SetEnv is a directive for mod_env, and mod_env doesn't support %{ENV:var} -- only mod_rewrite does this.  Don't forget that apache is modular, and modules define their own directives.  You can do this with mod_rewrite like this:

```
 RewriteRule .* -  [E=PROJECT_BASE:%{ENV:DOC_ROOT}]
  ... etc
```

I must ask, what are you really trying to do?  There must be a better way.  I can't think of any reason to define your LAYOUT_HOME variable in apache instead of php.

Comment: Thanks. You're right PHP is a good place to do this. Just bending things to see what can and cant be done.. should or should not be done is the next step =]

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to set environment variables in a RewriteRule. I was having module execution order with SetEnv and RewriteCond and this was just the thing to get the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getenv`, [doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php).

It will get any Environment Variable, just use it to get the one you set on Apache.

Comment: problem is its not working. Im not sure whats wrong or how to fix it

Comment: Can't you get that path from  `__FILE__`, for example?